# Ecuación polinómica en R

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo una pregunta que puede parecer muy simple pero como soy nueva en R pues me está costando. ¿Alguien sabe cómo resolver una ecuación polinómica en R? Necesito resolver la siguiente ecuación:

```
x^9 * (1-x)^4 = -125.7
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Sin entrar en temas de álgebra voy a decir simplemente que tu ecuación, podría escribirse así:

```
10*x^13 - 40*x^12 + 60*x^11 - 40*x^10 + 10*x^9 + 1257 = 0
```

Ver [este desarrollo](https://es.symbolab.com/solver/polynomial-equation-calculator/x%5E%7B9%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cleft(1-x%5Cright)%5E%7B4%7D%20%3D%20-125.7)

Lo cual ahora nos permite obtener las raíces, al tratarse de un polinomio de grado 13 vamos a tener 14 coeficientes que definimos en un vector:

```
z <- c(1257,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,-40,60,-40,10)
```

Y ahora sí podríamos usar la función base [`polyroot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/polyroot.html) para intentar resolver está ecuación:

```
polyroot(z)
 [1]  0.837406+1.278680i -1.034251+0.649532i -0.561473-1.145328i  0.837406-1.278680i
 [5]  0.111366+1.371093i -1.204211-0.000000i -1.034251-0.649532i  0.111366-1.371093i
 [9] -0.561473+1.145328i  1.450142+0.899623i  1.450142-0.899623i  1.798915+0.323637i
[13]  1.798915-0.323637i
```

En este caso la aproximación no compleja es `-1.204211-0.000000i`, lo cual podemos verificar:

```
x <- -1.204211
round(x^9 * (1-x)^4,1) == -125.7
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `polyroot()` para obtener las raíces del polinomio, que asumo es lo que quieres hallar, necesita desarrollar el polinomio en potencias de X para obtener los coeficientes que después se usan en la función. Fíjate en el help.